# hasMany returns empty,but sql return selection

Tags: sql, laravel

I have the Eloquemnt expression

```
 public function ratings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(commentRating::class,'comment_id','id');
    }
```

which return empty selection.

But debugging this with >toSql() i get the following:

```
select * from `comment_ratings` where `comment_ratings`.`comment_id` = ? and `comment_ratings`.`comment_id` is not null
```

And with getBindings it returns array
0:19.

So when i executing the  final sql query :

```
select * from `comment_ratings` where `comment_ratings`.`comment_id` = 19 and `comment_ratings`.`comment_id` is not null
```

I am getting the not empty result :
[image]

Why does Eloqument returns the null selection?

My comment model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\Models\Data\Items;
use App\Models\commentRating;

class Comment extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'body',
        'user_id',
        'item_id'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'user_id' => 'integer',
        'item_id' => 'integer',
    ];

    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Items::class, 'id');
    }

    public function ratings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(commentRating::class,'comment_id','id');
    }

    public function rated($user_id){
        return $this->ratings();
        // return $this->item_id;
        // $rated = commentRating::where('user_id', $user_id)->where('comment_id',$this->item_id)->first();
        // return $rated;
    }
}
```

I am executing this in my commentController method:

```
public function rated($user_id){
        return $this->ratings();
        // return $this->item_id;
        // $rated = commentRating::where('user_id', $user_id)->where('comment_id',$this->item_id)->first();
        // return $rated;
    }
```

Comment: can you add the full eloquent query?

Comment: this is full,i did add the model description and the controller method to question

Comment: in the controller, can you add the method `ratings()`? so we can trace the issue

Comment: this code should work: `Comment::with('ratings')->find(19)`, this will get the comment with id `19`, and load the ratings relation and append to the response

Comment: Yep,your code is working fine.I am getting the rating ratings
: 
[{id: 1, user_id: 1, comment_id: 19, created_at: "2022-12-04T12:35:39.000000Z",…}]
0
: 
{id: 1, user_id: 1, comment_id: 19, created_at: "2022-12-04T12:35:39.000000Z",…}
comment_id
: 
19
created_at
: 
"2022-12-04T12:35:39.000000Z"
id
: 
1
updated_at
: 
"2022-12-04T12:35:39.000000Z"
user_id
: 
1

Comment: Maybe the hasMany have any other condition to relationship to working fine?

Comment: it should not, this is why asked you to add the full code, so we can trace it and catch the issue

Comment: at all i am need just to get the flag was the comment rated or not . I am done thisby that code  public function rated($user_id,$comment_id){
        return commentRating::where('user_id', $user_id)->where('comment_id',$comment_id)->first() ? true:false;
    }

Comment: So maybe it was problem with naming database ids and models,anywhere thx for your help